# Pasting text with a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to paste some text with a vector:

```
v1 <- c(16,17,18)
paste ("the numbers in v1 are:",v1)
```

I would like to get:
    the numbers in v1 are: 16,17,18
but instead it get:

```
[1] "the numbers in v1 are: 16" "the numbers in v1 are: 17"
[3] "the numbers in v1 are: 18"
```

I would be grateful for advice to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to collapse `v1` first:

```
paste("the numbers in v1 are:", paste(v1, collapse = ","))
# [1] "the numbers in v1 are: 16,17,18"
```

Your code will first repeat `"the numbers in v1 are"` until it matches the length of `v1`, and then it will paste the elements of the vectors together by index.

Or

```
sprintf('the numbers in v1 are: %s', toString(v1))
# [1] "the numbers in v1 are: 16, 17, 18"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite right but it achieves the goal.

```
cat("the numbers in v1 are:", v1)
```